# Executable has error during runtime

Tags: c++

I have the following code which compiles properly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "INVESTMENT.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main()
{


    ifstream inputFile("jroth.csv");
    string sHolder; //used as placeholder for string
    float fHolder; //used as placeholder for float
    double dHolder; ///used as placeholder for double

//  while (inputFile.good())
    vector<int> InvestVector;  //will hold class (Investment) which contains string, double, and float
    for (int i=0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        Investment InvestVector[i]; //create new class for each line being pulled from .csv file
        getline(inputFile, sHolder, ',');  //pull in investment symbol as string
        InvestVector[i].setSymbol(sHolder); //store string in the class
        cout << InvestVector[i].getSymbol(); //verify string store properly
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As soon as the program runs, the executable crashes.  Any thoughts on why?

Comment: What does your debugger offer in the way of insight? If you're new to C++ try to avoid getting in the bad habit of `using namespace std`. The `std::` prefix is deliberate, it helps avoid collisions with names in your own code.

Comment: Not shown here is what `Investment` is. Any number of things could be going on in there. Is there any reason why the header file is in ALL CAPS?

Comment: In your `for` loop, you are using a *dynamic array*, which is not supported by the C++ standard.

Comment: Why are you doing `vector<int>`

Comment: `Investment InvestVector[i]` in the loop is not valid C++.  It is a compiler extension that does not do what your comment suggests.

Comment: The `InvestVector` defined in your `for` loop is a different variable than the `InvestVector` declared before the loop.

Comment: BTW, all the variables declared inside the `for` loop disappear when execution leaves the loop.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: It's called a "variable-length array" and you're right it's totally nonstandard, but supported through a gcc extension.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a C++ compiler with variable-length arrays, which is not standard C++, then this line:

```
Investment InvestVector[i];
```

creates an array with "i" places, numbered from 0 to i-1. Then these two lines:

```
InvestVector[i].setSymbol(sHolder);
cout << InvestVector[i].getSymbol();
```

will try to work with position number "i" of the array, that is, one past the end of the array.